# Data sharing with microservices

Tags: microservices

I am implementing an event-driven microservice architecture. Imagine the following scenario:

- **Chat service**: Ability to see conversations and send messages. Conversations can have multiple participants.
- **Registration-login service**: Deals with the registration of new users, and login.
- **User service**: Getting/updating user profiles.

The registration-login service emits the following event with the newly created user object:
`registration-new`
`login-success`
`logout-success`

The chat service then listens on `registration-new` and stores some fields of user in its own redis cache. It also listens on `login-success` and stores the token, and on `logout-success` to delete the token.

The user service has the following event: `user-updated`. When this is fired, a listener in the chat service updates the data corresponding to the user id in redis. Like the chat service, the user service also listens on `login-success` and `logout-success` and does the same thing as what the chat service does.

My question is the following: is this a good way to do this? It feels a bit counterintuitive to be sharing data everywhere. I need some advice on this. Thank you!

Comment: When you say "It feels a bit counterintuitive to be SHARING data everywhere.", do you mean "duplicating" or "distributing"? Because "sharing" usually means to have a common repository that everyone access.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that there's no other way. Microservices architecture puts lots of stress in avoiding data sharing so as to not create dependencies. That means that each microservice will have some data duplicated. That also means that there must exist a way of getting data from other contexts. The preferred methods strive for eventual consistency, such as sending messages to event sourcing or AMQP systems and subscribing to them. You can also use synchronous methods (RPC calls, distributed transactions). That creates additional technologic dependencies, but if you cannot accept eventual consistency it could be the only way.

Comment: This might not be a complete answer but it's not wrong either, whoever is downvoting should say why or offer an alternative answer

Comment: @Matt Thank you for the support! I don't get why my answer is incomplete, could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, to be fair I think it is complete, I think anyone down voting should always say why